# Undeclared Identifier, find Unit without using Google

Tags: delphi

Is there an "automagical" way in Delphi to lookup which unit an Undeclared Identifier possibly is in?

For example, I open up a new Project, with a `TEdit` and `TButton`. And I simply type:

```
TFile
```

I get an undeclared identifier, but in this case I am lucky because when pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, I get that it is in `System.IOUtils`. But sometimes, I am not so lucky.

Is there some sort of shortcut key, or how do you people do it?

(I must confess, I usually Google this up)

Comment: There's the "Find Unit" feature (Refactoring menu or Shift+Ctrl+A). But most often it fails, often with an access violation in the IDE. Probably Google is the best choice...

Comment: If F1 fails, next I do a Find in Files through Delphi's source files (or wherever is appropriate for the component I'm using, if it's a 3rd party one).

Comment: You can also have a command-line window open in the background, in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\NN.N\source` folder, and then do a `findstr /S /I /C:"TFile =" *.pas`.

Comment: Why using Google (tracking concerned) if you can use [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Delphi+TFile) (privacy concerned)? Finding type declarations in units also works there. Otherwise I do the same as @AndreasRejbrand with `findstr`, because that's a "find in files" tool that is guaranteed to exist on every Windows installation.

Comment: @AmigoJack : I am not concerned about tracking , but about no Internet for example . I do have my notices but not for everything.

Comment: For Delphi RTL/VCL/FMX, I use F1 which is quite reliable. For my own code and the components I like to use, I use [*MMX Code Explorer*](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/) which is a free tool that has an indexer. You can index whatever source code you have on your hard disk. Scanning the file could take a few minutes if you have a lot of sources (I have several thousands units to scan), but after that, search is instantaneous.

Comment: Since source files are basically just plain text files you can also configure your Windows Search to Index contents of PAS files and then use Windows Search for finding units that contain specific search term. No need for third party software. Works on low as Windows 2000. On Windows 10 or newer you can probably even use Cortana to search through your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following convenient methods that I know about:

1. The built in "[Find Unit](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Finding_Units_(Delphi))" refactoring of the IDE. Unfortunately I don't find it very reliable.
2. The "Uses Clause Manager" expert in [GExperts](https://gexperts.dummzeuch.de) (switch to the [Identifier tab](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/2018/08/04/improved-uses-clause-manager-in-gexperts/) on the right)
3. The "[Delphi Uses Helper](https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2021/03/introducing-delphi-uses-helper.html)" IDE plugin written by Stefan Glienke.

The comments list a few others that I think aren't that convenient (with the possible exception of the MMX Code Explorer which I don't know). The "[Grep Search](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?grep_search.html)" expert in GExperts might also help. Or instead of typing the search term into Google manually, you could use the "[Delphi Help Expert](https://blog.dummzeuch.de/delphi-help-expert/)" which allows you to specify a search engine of your choice which is then opened when you press F1 + a modifier key.

Comment: The best choice for me is Grep Search of GExperts, Find Unit in Delphi IDE crash with AE in about 80% of uses and in rest 20% it doesnt find anything even for Delphi classes.

Answer (score 1):

My choice in preferred order:

1. Alt + F11 - "Use unit" from list of units in active project, in case
   I know which unit I need.
2. Grep search of GExperts

I never use Find Unit of IDE, it crash almost always in last dozen versions of RAD Studio and after that I need to restart IDE and reload project group which takes way too much time compared to Grep search.

Probably you asking for something magical like in Android Studio - sorry, we don't have such tool in RAD Studio. Maybe it's time for someone to make it.

Comment: Have you ever tried the Uses Clause Manager's Identifier tab? It's much faster than Grep and works well for me.

Comment: @dummzeuch To be honest - I've never tried it, just because grep search always can give me some additional info in results and it's fast enough for my needs - in one of our projects group with about 1000 source code files it took less than a second, and about 2-3 secs in complete Source folder of RAD Studio.

Comment: What does that "magical" thingy in Android Studio you mention do?

Comment: @dummzeuch I refer to functionality in Android Studio about auto add import of package when you use class for first time in your source file.